# Evaluating Prefix operations using a Queue in C

Tags: c, algorithm, queue, prefix

Im toying with the problem of prefix evaluations, and I want to evaluate them using only a queue. Here is my pseudocode

```
while Q has more than 1 element
   if the pattern operand, number, number occurs
         op=dequeue(Q)
         num1=dequeue(Q)
         num2=dequeue(Q)
         eval=evaluate(op,num1,num2)
         enqueue(Q,eval)
   else
         elem=dequeue(Q)
         enqueue(Q,elem)
```

I think my logic is correct for well formed prefix operations, but I'm not sure how to account for invalid prefix syntax, such as 10+4.

Right now, my algorithm would dequeue the 10 and then enqueue it at the end, which would then become proper prefix and be evaluated, but I do not want it to. Is there some pre condition to make sure the syntax is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function to pop the first element of the queue without dequeuing it, you could use it in your else path with a while(first element not operand) to dequeue the invalid elements. This would guarantee you at least, that the first item in your queue is an operand.